# Defining the notion of a perfect number in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose I wanted to define in first order logic a predicate of natural numbers, $perfect$, where $perfect(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ iff $n$ is a perfect number (i.e, a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper divisors).

Could I definitionally introduce a sum operator to do this?

If variables ranged over sets (so we had something like first-order set theory), how would we do this? How could we define the sum operator in this language?

Comment: In set theory we can construct a function acting on natural numbers which we call sum. This is done using recursion, perhaps you know how to construct this already? Of course, this function is a set itself, so we can define this sum function in the language of set theory. Similarly we could do the same for multiplication. The biggest challenge lies with can we define the $perfect(n)$ relation using these?

Comment: To define something, you need to first specify your language, and your structure, or at least your theory if you want to have some abstract definition (e.g. Peano Arithmetic). Definitions don't exist in vacuum.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I intend a structure that models first order set theory (so the elements of the domain are sets) and in which we can define the addition operation.

Comment: You haven't answered my question, which hints to me that perhaps it is a good idea that you revise the basics of what it means to be *first-order definable* in *a structure*.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I mean a first order logic in which the Peano axioms are laid down as logical axioms and a model in which the variables range over sets.

Comment: Well, Peano axioms describe the natural numbers, and their first-order objects are not sets. So again, I reiterate my recommendation above.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I mean a first order set theory in which we have defined via it the natural numbers, and thus can lay down the Peano axioms as non-logical axioms on the natural numbers, where natural numbers are certain sets.